# Wiki-Table float-right won't align

Tags: mediawiki

I tried to create a table for a MediaWiki (`MediaWiki 1.21.1`, `PHP 5.3.29 (cgi-fcgi)`, `MySQL 5.5.38-log`), but I had a problem aligning it: I'd like to let the text flow around the table, but it doesn't.

```
{|class="wikitable" style="float:right"
! colspan="2"|[[Datei:LIpsmum.png|200px|center|]]
|-
!|Name
|KLorem ipsum
|-
!|Geburt
|1939
|-
!|Verwandlung
|1960
|-
!|Erzeuger
|[[Lorem]]
|-
!|Clan
|[[:Kategorie:Lorem|Lorem]]
|-
!|Generation
|10
|-}
```

This is how I would like it to look like http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Theo_Bell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wiki code is malformatted, so that the table never ends. **The table should be closed with `|}`**, not `|-}`. And while we are on it, your `<th>`  cells should start with only `!`, not `!|`. This [will work](http://xn--ssongsmat-v2a.nu/w/index.php?title=Anv%C3%A4ndare:Leo/Test&oldid=33741):

```
{|class="wikitable" style="float:right"
  ! colspan="2"|[[Datei:LIpsmum.png|200px|center|]]
  |-
  !Name
  |KLorem ipsum
  ...
|}
```

You might want to read through [the documentation on MediaWiki tables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables).